# Can't select elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, preventdefault

I want to prevent a link from taking the user to another page.
When I try to select elements with getElementById("id"), it works fine. When I try to select by using $("#id"), however, it doesn't work. To clarify, this works:
https://jsfiddle.net/1nwaptL9/

but this doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/7vkepm9e/1/

I realise both of these fiddles do actually work, but when I load the HTML files in Chrome, the one with the jQuery selection doesn't work. Since the source code I've included below works fine in JSFiddle, but not in Chrome, I suspect I've done something wrong, but JSFiddle doesn't process links or something like that. Any help would be appreciated!

Source code that doesn't work:

```
<html>
<body>
<a id="preventlink" href="http://youtube.com"> click here </a>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var link=$("#preventlink");
link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()}, false)

    </script>
```

Comment: You didn't properly include jquery in your fiddle. And even if you did, you're not using jQuery properly. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7vkepm9e/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery creates a jQuery instance, if you want the actual DOM element, you can do the following:

```
var link = $("#preventlink")[0];
```

Or, just keep using jQuery to add events:

```
$("#preventlink")
    .click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

## Getting the element from the jQuery instance:

```js
var link = $("#preventlink")[0];
link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="preventlink" href="http://youtube.com"> click here </a>
```

## Sticking with just jQuery:

```js
$("#preventlink").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="preventlink" href="http://youtube.com"> click here </a>
```

See [jQuery's doc](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/) on the subject

Comment: `.click('click'`?

Comment: @j08691, thanks! What I get for copy-pasting code from the OP

Comment: Thanks for the help, but 1. what you wrote didn't work, and 2. I don't know what happened, but now I can't get it to work without jQuery either.

Comment: @ChristofferCorfieldAakre, did you take the element from the jQuery instance with `[0]`. Also, I updated my answer to demonstrate the two different ways I explained.

Answer (score 3):

This is because addEventListener is a javascript function. It's not defined for jquery. For jquery you can use bind function. Below is the sample code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var link=$("#preventlink");
 link.bind('click', function(e){
  
    e.preventDefault();})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<a id="preventlink" href="http://youtube.com"> click here </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing jQuery with vanilla JS:

`$("#id")` -- **jQuery**

`document.getElementById("id")` -- **Vanilla JS**

Try to use either one of them.

**jQuery:**

```
$("#preventlink").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

**Vanilla JS:**

```
  var link=document.getElementById("preventlink");
  link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()}, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#preventlink").on('click', function (e)
{ 
    e.preventDefault (); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more jQuery way of doing what you are looking for

```js
var $link = $("#preventlink");

$link.on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("link clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <body>
  <a id="preventlink" href="http://youtube.com"> click here </a>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```